# {Discord.py-rewrite} Bot commands don't work while I have an "On Message" event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a joke discord bot, but I still want some functionality. I have a few commands, they all work perfectly unless I have my "on message" event. The "on message" event works just fine, but the commands don't. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I am very confused as I have had "on message" events and commands in the past, and they have worked just fine. My code is the following.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = 'token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as: {bot.user.name}')
    print(f'With ID: {bot.user.id}')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong! Latency: {0}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 751679038841553008:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:
            
            if ''.join(message.content.split()).lower()== "egg":
                return
            else:
                await message.channel.send("{} You fool. You absolute buffoon, it is illegal to say anything other than 'egg' in this server. I hope you feel the shame in side you. Us only saying 'egg' in this channel brings peace to our server, and you thinking your above everyone? above ME? You {}, have messed up. I want you to take a long time to reflect your self.".format(message.author.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        return

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

So, in summary, it seems like the "on message" events and the commands don't want to work at the same time.

### EDIT

I am very much aware that my "On Message" event doesn't make much sense, its an inside joke between me and my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the default provided `on_message()` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message()` event.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.channel.id == 751679038841553008:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:

            if ''.join(message.content.split()).lower() == "egg":
                return
            else:
                await message.channel.send(
                    "{} You fool. You absolute buffoon, it is illegal to say anything other than 'egg' in this server. I hope you feel the shame in side you. Us only saying 'egg' in this channel brings peace to our server, and you thinking your above everyone? above ME? You {}, have messed up. I want you to take a long time to reflect your self.".format(
                        message.author.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it doesn't seem to have worked. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know and I will try it. Thanks. EDIT: I put it at the beginning of the event and its working, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I will edit my answer to reflect your solution. Good luck.